# Using Windows command shell for creating multiple files

Tags: windows, shell, cmd

Is there a way of creating multiple files in Windows by using its own command prompt (`cmd.exe`) or terminal emulator if you call it, just like the below simple one liner would do in any Unix-like system? Note that I'm talking about a situation where I can't use any alternative terminal emulators like PowerShell or [Win 32 ports of GNU utils](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/).

```
for i in `seq 10` ; do `touch $i.txt`; done
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```dos
for /l %a in (1 1 10) do type nul > "%a.txt"
```

For each value in the sequence from 1 in steps of 1 up to 10, create (`>` redirection) a empty file (`type nul` reads nothing and writes nothing) using the value in the sequence as filename (the value in the `for` replaceable parameter)

The command is written to be used from command line. Inside a batch file percent signs need to be escaped (doubling them), replacing `%a` with `%%a`

Answer (score 6):

Use windows syntax:

```
for %A in (1 2 3) do type nul > file%A.txt
```

or

```
for %A in (1 2 3) do echo.> file%A.txt
```

or

```
for %A in (1 2 3) do copy nul > file%A.txt
```